# Unstaged changes left after abrupt shut down

Tags: git, unstage

I'm working on a git repository using git-scm.

While choosing unstaged files to commit, my laptop abruptly shut down due to low battery. After restart, all my unstaged changes were gone even if the changes were still there in files.

Any solution for this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with "all my unstaged changes were gone even if the changes were still there in files", what is the result of `git status`?

Comment: What about `git diff --cached` , do you see what you're looking for ?

Comment: I mean the list of unstagged changes doesn't show up in Git GUI but actually the changes are still there and were not reverted.

Comment: both git diff --cached and git status return error: bad signature
fatal: index file corrupt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to rebuild the index and start over from the last commit:

```
rm -rf .git/index
git reset
```

This should leave you with your changes in the working tree and with an "empty" index.

I recomend that you do a backup before doing this.